# Only few Levels Of Dummy Variables are significant

Tags: regression, categorical-data

When I run a mutiple regression on 3 independent variables(2 dummy variables with multiple levels each and a metric variable).

In my result only few levels of a dummy variable are significant. The result of the levels for the same dummy variable are insignifcant.

How do I interpret it? Is the whole variable with multiple levels inisignificant or do the rest of the levels exhbit the base category behaviour?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I cannot make a comment (as i'm new to this forum). 
This can help you : 
[Significance of dummy variables in regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78644/significance-of-dummy-variables-in-regression)

Comment: I wonder if you may be confusing *dummy variable* (typically a synonym for 0/1-coded *indicator variable*), with *categorical variable*. Dummy variables genneraly have exactly two levels. There are alternative ways and analytic reasons to code nominal/dichotomous/binary variables than 0/1, but that's usually the simplest.