# Show equivalence of spline and Gaussian process

Tags: regression, gaussian-process

[This CrossValidated question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144634/splines-vs-gaussian-process-regression) was answered with the statement that **"splines are just a special case of Gaussian Process regression"**. I like to show this equivalence in practice, but fail to do so. Can we create an example with real data to show that a GP trend, and a spline trend, yield the same result?

I tried it using the Python libraries `scipy` to generate splines, and `scikit-learn` for a GP with a radial basis function (RBF) kernel, [also known as a squared-exponential kernel](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels.RBF.html). Splines are supposedly a special case of GPs with this kernel.

First, I generate synthetic test data. A sine as an example for a simple variation, plus some noise:

```py
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)
points = 200
x = np.linspace(0, 1, points)
y = np.sin(x * 20)
noise = np.random.normal(0, 0.1, points)
y += noise
```

The GP trend:

```py
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import RBF
length = 0.1
kernel = RBF(length, (length, length))
GP = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel).fit(x.reshape(-1, 1), y)
trend_GP = GP.predict(x.reshape(-1, 1))
```

For the spline, we need to set the [smoothing parameter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline) so that both curves match. By method of least squares minimization, I found `s=1.43` to be closest in this example.

```py
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline
spline = UnivariateSpline(x, y, s=1.43, k=3)
trend_spline = spline(x)
```

Now we can plot the scatter data and both curves.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(x, y, s=3, color='black')
plt.plot(x, trend_GP, color='blue')
plt.plot(x, trend_spline, color='red')
plt.show()
```

The curves are similar, but not identical:

```py
plt.plot(x, trend_GP - trend_spline, color='black')
plt.show()
```

Comment: There's a known equivalence between *certain types of splines* and Gaussian process models using *certain covariance functions*. But, why do you think that this holds for the RBF kernel in particular? I don't see this mentioned in the post you linked. The other places where I've seen this equivalence demonstrated (e.g. Rasmussen&Williams chapter 6) use a covariance function explicitly constructed to mimic splines (not RBF).

Comment: If the equivalence holds for _certain types of splines_: Which types are these? And which covariance functions? I would appreciate any working example of equivalence.

Comment: Section 6.3 [here](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW6.pdf) gives a good example